# Is there a mongodb server for Cypress to be able to query inside my tests

Tags: mongodb, cypress

I need to query mongo inside my Cypress tests to basically see if my POST is updating some fields, but I don't see a npm package for it like there is for sql server. Googling it I only see documentation and examples on how to seed the db.
Any thoughts, comments?
Thank you

Comment: How do you run your tests? If in Docker, why not add a new container?

Comment: The tests are not running currently in docker. I would still need a way of querying it. You mean it would be easier if I have the db in an image? If so, please provide the details. I'm open to try anything because db connection is very important for these tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/testing-mongo-with-cypress/

The gist of it:

-- plugins/index.js

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

const { connect } = require('../../db')

module.exports = async (on, config) => {
  const db = await connect()
  const pizzas = db.collection('pizzas')

  on('task', {
    async clearPizzas() {
      console.log('clear pizzas')
      await pizzas.remove({})

      return null
    },
  })
}
```

-- db.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI
if (!uri) {
  throw new Error('Missing MONGO_URI')
}

const client = new MongoClient(uri)
async function connect() {
  // Connect the client to the server
  await client.connect()

  return client.db('foods')
}

async function disconnect() {
  // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
  await client.close()
}

module.exports = { connect, disconnect }
```

Change the line `await pizzas.remove({})` to whatever query you want to run, I'll assume you know how to get the result of the query and assert it.

Comment: Any additional package I should download? After doing this I get a "Cypress is not defined" error

Comment: Not really, take a look at dependencies here: https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-example-mongodb/blob/main/package.json
If you'd like a more tailored example, then please share all the code you can, otherwise it's kinda difficult to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: Solved it. Somehow Cypress didn't like that I was using import instead of require to get the mongo client. Thank you1

Comment: Just published a mongodb plugin for cypress: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mongodb
Should be easier to use than going through the post above.